# paths and symbols missing from eclipse(4.12, C++, Arduino)

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-cdt

I am trying to get some third party libraries to work with eclipse (4.12) and I do not have the "Paths and symbols" menu option under project properties.

My understanding is that I need this to install libraries, is this wrong? if so is there another way to do it in this version of eclipse?

I created clean C++ and Arduino projects and they also lacked the menu option.